# How to integrate Amadeus GDS with my travel domain. I have IATA certification

Tags: amadeus

I have IATA certification and now want to integrate Amadeus GDS. I need to discuss this with experts.

Comment: What, if anything, is `catification`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your local Amadeus office - you can find it in our [Global Directory](http://www.amadeus.com/web/amadeus/en_1A-corporate/Amadeus-Home/About-us/Contact-us/Amadeus-local-offices/1319560217723-Page-AMAD_LocalOfficesPpal).

Since you're asking on Stack Overflow, I guess you'd be most interested in programmatic access through Web Services or APIs. Once you're signed with your local office, you can access these through [developers.amadeus.com](https://developers.amadeus.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can contact with Amadeus using Amadeus website http://www.amadeus.com their account manager will revert of your request and give you the Amadeus sandbox test API access for your product development. Amadeus Will only allow athe citified technology company and Only IATA Certificated Travel Agency